# Using one bigger table or OneToOne Relation?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an entity Company with different attributes.

One of the attributes is logo, but logo itself is characterized by other attributes, like filename and type.

The relation between company and logo is one to one, an is mandatory to have a logo.

Should I add everything as attributes/columns of company or should I create a separate table for Logo and his characteristics ?

Using same table I avoid a join or another query in the database, plus more codding, what are the advantages to use a separate logo table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of a separate logo table is that you can scan the `companies` table without having to read the logo information.  If it is just a handful of columns, this might not make a different.  Under some circumstances, it could.

One argument in favor of a separate table would be whether other entities want to connect specifically to the logo and not to the company.  If so, a separate id would allow such foreign key relationships.

I might challenge the notion that a company has exactly one logo.  First, companies can have multiple brands with their own logos or they may have different logos in different geographies/languages.  Second, the logo might change over time.  If you want to keep a history, then another table would be a no-brainer.